# How to execute a cleanup script on exec-maven-plugin:exec failure?

Tags: maven, exec-maven-plugin

I'm currently using the maven plugin `exec-maven-plugin` to execute a script, this script launches several java programs corresponding to an `integration test`, if the test passes, everything is stopped properly by a `cleanup script` executed later in the build.

My problem is when the test fails because when the plugin `exec-maven-plugin` fails it stops the build immediately such that my `cleanup script` is never called which means that my java programs are never stopped.

So is there a way to execute my `cleanup script` even if my `integration test` fails?

So far, I added `1` as `successCode` to my integration test to ensure that my `cleanup script` is called but it is not good enough because the build is seen has a build success which is not the case.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I finally did:

1. I added `1` as [`success code`](http://site.kuali.org/maven/plugins/exec-maven-plugin/1.1/exec-mojo.html#successCodes) to my `integration test` in order to make sure that the `cleanup script` is always called.
2. I defined the property [`outputFile`](http://site.kuali.org/maven/plugins/exec-maven-plugin/1.1/exec-mojo.html#outputFile) to my `integration test` in order to redirect the standard output streams into a file to be tested later
3. After my `cleanup script`, I check for a given pattern in file created in step #2 using a command of type `cat {my-file} | grep {my-pattern} >/dev/null` in order to know if the `integration test` passed or not, if the pattern cannot be found, it will make the build fails otherwise the build will pass.